# Stuck/hung upon connect usb device

Tags: linux, usb, troubleshooting, rc

I have a device the is coming up 'busy' as soon as I plug it in. I even sniffed the usb connection and all looks normal. How do I find out what is capturing the device? How do I free it up?

```
root@coined:~# VBoxManage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

UUID:               a287040d-bdf3-488a-8c45-9ab0a04c8263
VendorId:           0x04d8 (04D8)
ProductId:          0x000a (000A)
Revision:           1.0 (0100)
Port:               3
USB version/speed:  2/1
Manufacturer:       TECHNOBIT HEX ASIC Miner.
Product:            HEX16C-Avalon2 ASIC Miner
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/010
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               511d4477-4b2d-4117-b30b-251f4c0c65d8
VendorId:           0x04d9 (04D9)
ProductId:          0x1605 (1605)
Revision:           1.1 (0101)
Port:               2
USB version/speed:  1/1
Manufacturer:
Product:            USB Keyboard
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.3//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/003
Current State:      Captured
```

---

```
root@coined:~# udevadm info /dev/vboxusb/003/010
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4
N: bus/usb/003/010
E: BUSNUM=003
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/010
E: DEVNUM=010
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=HEX16C-Avalon2_ASIC_Miner
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=HEX16C-Avalon2\x20ASIC\x20Miner
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=CDC RS-232 Emulation Demo
E: ID_MODEL_ID=000a
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=TECHNOBIT_HEX_ASIC_Miner._HEX16C-Avalon2_ASIC_Miner
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0000:
E: ID_VENDOR=TECHNOBIT_HEX_ASIC_Miner.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=TECHNOBIT\x20HEX\x20ASIC\x20Miner.
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Microchip Technology, Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=04d8
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=265
E: PRODUCT=4d8/a/100
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=2/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=118225936790
```

Comment: The `lsof /dev/<your dev>` command can show you which processes are using/accessing your device. Could you post the output to see if there is anything interesting? Can you also tell us what is your OS?

Comment: Can you also do a `udevadm info /dev/vboxusb/003/010` and post the output? `lsof` might not print anything because it lists only open files. It's a wild guess.

Comment: @lgeorget I just added it.